# Link to another website with the same url path

Tags: redirect, links

Can I add a button on the menu bar that take the user to another website with the same current path?

For example, I am in the page with url:

```
www.example.com/test/blank
```

And when press the button it takes me to the url:

```
www.example.com **/ar** /test/blank
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using WordPress Multisite Network.

See this tutorial for same:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Also, if you don't want multisite, for some reason, you can create a sub-folder in WordPress root of existing and install a separate WordPress in it.

Comment: I have already installed another WordPress in a sub-folder, but I want the button take me to the other WordPress with the same path (/test/blank in the example above) not to the home page.

Is that possible without using WordPress Multisite Network?

Comment: Have you tried giving the complete link? As in `www.example.com/ar/test/blank`? And make sure link exist.

Comment: Yes, this work for only one page.
I am sorry for not being very specific. But what I actually need is changing the path according to the current page path. So if I am on the page: (www.example.com/test/blank) it will take me to (www.example.com **/ar** /test/blank), and if I am on (www.example.com/another/test) it will take me to (www.example.com **/ar** /another/test)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$cur_url = get_permalink();
$new_url = str_replace('example.com','example.com/ar',$cur_url);

echo "<a href='".$new_url."'>Link</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you.

Can I use this with a link in a menu?